# App store Rejected app because app use more entitlements which do not have matching functionality

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

my app has just been rejected by Apple for the following reason:

[image]

Now, the problem is simple, in Xcode, under the Capabilities tab, I don't have enable Maps. And this is not all.

Here is my App Id:

[image]

Maps are disabled, but In-App Purchases is enabled. And If I click on edit, I can't un-check In-App Purchases...

What should I do next?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try to disable In-App-Purchases from your app's identifier/certificate in the developer portal. (http://developer.apple.com)

It most likely is not a thing that can be resolved in Xcode.

Comment: This is the problem, from developer portal  i'm not able to disable this, because this is the only capability I can't uncheck. And , if I create a new App ID, by difaul in app purcheses is on